# Bulk removing Wifi networks from an iOS device

Tags: ios, network, wifi, security

This article, ["What we give away when we log on to a public Wi-Fi network"](https://decorrespondent.nl/1101/What-we-give-away-when-we-log-on-to-a-public-Wi-Fi-network/31040493-53737dba), demonstrates how dangerous it is for you to turn on Wi-fi on your phone. It advertises the name of every network it has connected to. And will connect to any network named, for example, “Starbucks”, even if you are not near a Starbucks.

I know you can turn this off when you are in range of a network by opening the Wi-Fi settings tab, clicking a few times and then checking “Forget Network.” But it doesn’t seem like there is a tool for managing these in bulk.

I was wondering if there are any tools—built-in or otherwise—for manually removing networks from the auto-join list.

Mac OS X for example allows you to add/delete/reorder networks:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can completely reset network settings under `Settings > General > Reset`.

Comment: Right, but this is a nuclear option. I'm wishing for a bulk edit/remove, not just "delete everything."

Comment: You can manually remove each one, or use the above settings item, but it is not possible to mass remove or edit them. iOS does not provide this capability directly, and third-party apps cannot modify system settings like this.

Answer (score 1):

If you own a Mac logged in to the same Apple ID, enabling iCloud Keychain will cause your devices to share network names.

Deleting them from your Mac will then delete them from your iOS devices logged in to the same Apple ID.

I am not aware of an iOS-specific way to achieve this.